# Conditional count with zero with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, count, zero

I'd like to count the use of Tool A in a data set, but also want to include the zero use of Tool A.

My data set example is as below;

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5)
Tool <- c("A","B","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B")
df <-data.frame(ID,Tool)
```

I want to count the number of Tool A use by membersID.

So my desired out put is

[image]
Please use pipeline to answer my question.

I can do without zero by using filter as below but I really need to add zero. (Don't want to add manually)
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may first `summarise` the data to count number of `Tool` `"A"` in each `ID` and then `count` the counts.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(ToolA = sum(Tool == "A")) %>%
  count(ToolA, name = "count")

# ToolA   count
#  <int> <int>
#1     0     1
#2     1     3
#3     2     1
```

Comment: Or in `base R` `with(df, stack(table(rowsum(+(Tool == "A"), ID)[,1])))[2:1]`